# ASP.NET keep alive page using aspx vs. html

Tags: asp.net

I have having trouble with my hosted site taking a long time to render the first page when it has not been accessed for a while.  I wanted to create a keep alive page that I would call every 15 minutes to make sure the site stays up and running.  Can I create an html page or must I create an aspx page for this to work?  Will the thread pool recognize the html page that is not part of my ASP.NET project and make sure the site is not shut down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to create a page which hit's the .net process. You can do an html page, but you're going to have to have something on that page that hit's the asp.net process.

Comment: I think *any* request to the site would work on IIS7 configured such that ASP.NET handles all requests.